# how to list all the people submitted in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently in my job, we have a system that searches people in our database through the last 5 digits of their social security. However, there are many people who may have the same combination of digits, and in that case, the system displays all the people with that combination. i.e:

```
Social     firstName     lastName     Age
55555     John           Doe          24
55555     Michael        Jordan       51
55555     Mike           Tyson        48
```

I'm not interested in the search function, but I would like to know how can I display all the people in my database(onclick) in the same way the system in my job does it. I will be using javascript because its the only language I know. However, can I even perform this task with JS? Here is what I have so far, it will be a mix of code and plain english (to describe what I want to do) :

```
<body>
<h1>Please enter your information</h1>
<form>
 First name : <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
 Last name : <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
 Age : <input type="text" id="age"><br>
</form>
<button onclick="displayInfo()">Submit</button>

<div class="database">
  <table id="myPeeps">  <!-- Would tables be best for this? -->
  </table>
</div>

<script>
 var aName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
 var bName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
 var personAge = document.getElemntById('age').value;

 function person(one,two,three) {  //get the values from above and create a new object
  this.firstName = one;
  this.lastName = two;
  this.age = three;
 }

function displayInfo() {
create a new <tr> based on the number of people I have.
<td>PersonCreated.firstName here</td>
<td>PersonCreated.lastName here</td>
<td>PeronCreated.age here</td>

prepend newly created table row and table data to id ('myPeeps')
}
</script>
</body>
```

This may be a lot to ask for, but please help a newbie out. Ive been trying to do this for weeks, and I might not be in the level of javascript I need to be to perform this, but your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can create elements and append them pretty easily. Check out a tutorial or two and see if you dont find a solution that way.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Comment: @TankorSmash Yea jquery would be easier for me as well, but Im at a point where I vaguely know how to mix jquery and objects(especially complex objects). Also, im sure there is going to be a lot of .length and maybe loops used in ways that I have not been introduced to as of yet. I think I can perform this task, but it would be hundreds of lines of code. Im looking for new ideas and concepts that would spark new ways of thinking for this specific task. any ideas?

Comment: Use `createElement` to create the new table elements, and `appendChild` to add them to the DOM. If you know Javascript, as you've said, these should be familiar concepts.

Comment: @Barmar yea I'm familiar with those concepts. What Im having trouble with is how would I make all the people submitted from the input field into objects?

Comment: @David im not familiar with that concept, I will do more research on it, thank you.

Comment: @Walt You get the information from the input field, and then put it into the `textContent` of the new element. E.g. `var newCell = document.createElement('td'); newCell.textContent = this.firstName;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting a new row into your table can be achieved with something like this:

```
var $row = $("<tr><td>" + firstName + "</td></tr>");
$("#myPeeps").append($row);
```

I've just added the first table cell. Here is a more complete example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/h1nff261/).

Also, you can put your values into an object simply by:

```
var myobj = {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 22};
```

As I see, you already got the field values from the form, so you just put those in.

Comment: thank you for that! but how would I create the people submitted from the input field into objects? Thats where im really struggling.

Comment: I see. I modified my answer. Is the second part helpful?

Comment: Worked perfectly ! I replaced the names you created with the stored value of each input fields and it worked just how I wanted ! thanks a lot @zord!